# Seleção/Limpeza de informações em uma coluna

Tags: string, r

Possuo um banco de dados com milhares de linhas, porem em uma das colunas os dados estão desta forma:

```
XLOCAL
Estirão do Equador, Rio Javari (04°27'S;71°30'W)
Alto Rio Paru de Oeste, Posto Tiriós (02°15'N;55°59'W)
Ipixuna do Pará, Rodovia Belém-Brasília km 92/93 (02°26'S;47°30'W)
Aurora do Pará, Rodovia Belém-Brasília km 86 (02°04'S;47°33'W)
```

Gostaria de ajuda para deixar apenas as coordenadas, removendo todos os textos,  parenteses e ponto e virgula. 
Ficaria assim:

```
 XLOCAL
04°27'S 71°30'W
02°15'N 55°59'W
```

Tentei usar strings e gsub porem não tive sucesso. Exemplo do que tentei.

```
df <- c("sdasdad (04°27'S;71°30'W)", "zxczxczcxz (01°40'N;51°23'W)")
grep("^([[:punct:]])", df, value=TRUE)
pattern <- "[[:alpha:]]"
gsub("^.[[:alpha:]]", df, fixed=F)
```

resultado

```
[1] " (04°27';71°30')" " (01°40';51°23')" #Reparem que ele removeu também "N", "S", "W" das coordenadas.
```

O banco de dados é de museu, eles não estão disponíveis online, tem que organizar para disponibilizar online.
Me ajudem, são milhares de linhas para remover manualmente.
Muito obrigado desde já.

Comment: Coloque mais informações amigo, qual banco é ? Qual código já tentou utilizar? Qual erro aparece?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que na pergunta complicou a regex demais. Veja assim.
Primeiro ficar só com o que está entre `(` e `)`. Como estes caracteres são caracteres especiais é preciso usar `\\(` e `\\)`. É isso que o `sub` faz.
Depois substituir o ponto e vírgula `;` por um espaço. Para isso usei o `gsub` mas como só há um `;` também pode ser o `sub`.

```
gsub(";", " ", sub("^.*\\((.*)\\)", "\\1", XLOCAL))
#[1] "04°27'S 71°30'W" "02°15'N 55°59'W" "02°26'S 47°30'W"
#[4] "02°04'S 47°33'W"
```

Isto é equivalente (é exatamente a mesma coisa) ao seguinte, dividido em duas instruções para ser mais legível.

```
tmp <- sub("^.*\\((.*)\\)", "\\1", XLOCAL)
XLOCAL <- gsub(";", " ", tmp)
```

**Dados em formato `dput`.**

```
XLOCAL <-
c("Estirão do Equador, Rio Javari (04°27'S;71°30'W)", 
"Alto Rio Paru de Oeste, Posto Tiriós (02°15'N;55°59'W)", 
"Ipixuna do Pará, Rodovia Belém-Brasília km 92/93 (02°26'S;47°30'W)", 
"Aurora do Pará, Rodovia Belém-Brasília km 86 (02°04'S;47°33'W)")
```

Esta instrução cria um **vetor**. Se quiser uma dataframe, depois de correr a instrução acima, faça

```
dados <- data.frame(XLOCAL)
```

A seguir, no código onde está apenas `XLOCAL` deverá ser `dados$XLOCAL`.

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
data = read.delim(file.choose(), header = T)

library("stringr")

new_string = str_sub(data$XLOCAL, start = -16)

str_sub(new_string, start = 1, end=15)
#[1] "04°27'S;71°30'W" "02°15'N;55°59'W" "02°26'S;47°30'W" "02°04'S;47°33'W"
```